# Replacing one HTML table with another using the display method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I have a series of tables to display, depending on the googlemaps api polygon that the user has clicked on.  Code as follows:

HTML

```html
<div id="adilaDIV" class="boxOne" style="display:none">
  <table id="adilaTable" class="table" >
    <tr>
      <td>ADILABAD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Population</td>
      <td>2,930,604</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Percent Adults</td>
      <td>81%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Life Expectancy</td>
      <td>65</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="khamDIV" class="boxOne" style="display:none">
  <table id="khamTable" class="table" >
    <tr>
      <td>KHAMMAM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Population</td>
      <td>3,654,765</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Percent Adults</td>
      <td>81%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Life Expectancy</td>
      <td>65</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Javascript (with Googlemaps api)

```js
// Add a listener for the click event.
adilabadBorder.addListener('click', showPanelAdila);

//Show table with info
function showPanelAdila() {
  document.getElementByClassName('boxOne').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('adilaDIV').style.display="block";
  initialize();
}

// Add a listener for the click event.
khammamBorder.addListener('click', showPanelKham);

//Show table with info
function showPanelKham() {
  document.getElementByClassName('boxOne').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('khamDIV').style.display="block";
  initialize();
}
```

I require that when the user has clicked their second+ district, the old district table is hidden and the new district table displays.

I have tried various other code but the above is the closest I've come to making it work:

The toggle method generated no response from the browser:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

As did the jQuery model solution:

```js
$("#hide").click(function(){
  $("p").hide();
});

$("#show").click(function(){
  $("p").show();
});
```

In my current 'solution' I am attempting to hide any of the boxOne Divs that might be displaying currently when the user selects a new district polygon (I have 29 districts).  So hiding by class seems the right catch-all way to go about this but it doesn't work.  However - if I use `getElementById` with just one district, instead of `getElementByClassName`, the code works.  The previous table hides and the new one shows.

Comment: I always store the active 'table' in a variable, so the code always knowns which tables are already visible and which aren't. You can also reuse the click ahndler for each table and then jsut refer to the clicked table with event.target. No need to have exactly the same code for each, sicne the only sdiff seems to be the name of the div.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that there is no function `getElementByClassName` (I get a javascript error with your code `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function`).  The function that does what you want is `getElementsByClassName`, but as its name suggests, it returns an array of elements, so you need to iterate through that array to hide each element with that class, then you can show the div you are interested in.

```
function hideAllBoxOne() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('boxOne');
  for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

//Show table with info
function showPanelAdila() {
  hideAllBoxOne();
  document.getElementById('adilaDIV').style.display = "block";
}


//Show table with info
function showPanelKham() {
  hideAllBoxOne()
  document.getElementById('khamDIV').style.display = "block";
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wokg5dtt/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(17, 80),
      zoom: 6,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var Khammam = {
    "formatted_address": "Khammam, Telangana 507001, India",
    "geometry": {
      "bounds": {
        "south": 17.1980713,
        "west": 80.09917259999997,
        "north": 17.2986392,
        "east": 80.20169729999998
      },
      "location": {
        "lat": 17.2472528,
        "lng": 80.15144469999996
      }
    }
  };
  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var KhammamCoords = [{
    lat: Khammam.geometry.bounds.south,
    lng: Khammam.geometry.bounds.west
  }, {
    lat: Khammam.geometry.bounds.south,
    lng: Khammam.geometry.bounds.east
  }, {
    lat: Khammam.geometry.bounds.north,
    lng: Khammam.geometry.bounds.east
  }, {
    lat: Khammam.geometry.bounds.north,
    lng: Khammam.geometry.bounds.west
  }];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var khammamBorder = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: KhammamCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  khammamBorder.setMap(map);

  var Adilabad = {
      "formatted_address": "Adilabad, Telangana 504001, India",
      "geometry": {
        "bounds": {
          "south": 19.6282789,
          "west": 78.50087639999992,
          "north": 19.696577,
          "east": 78.55979920000004
        },
        "location": {
          "lat": 19.6640624,
          "lng": 78.5320107
        },
        "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport": {
          "south": 19.6282789,
          "west": 78.50087639999992,
          "north": 19.696577,
          "east": 78.55979920000004
        }
      }
    }
    // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var AdilabadCoords = [{
    lat: Adilabad.geometry.bounds.south,
    lng: Adilabad.geometry.bounds.west
  }, {
    lat: Adilabad.geometry.bounds.south,
    lng: Adilabad.geometry.bounds.east
  }, {
    lat: Adilabad.geometry.bounds.north,
    lng: Adilabad.geometry.bounds.east
  }, {
    lat: Adilabad.geometry.bounds.north,
    lng: Adilabad.geometry.bounds.west
  }];
  // Construct the polygon.
  var adilabadBorder = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: AdilabadCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  adilabadBorder.setMap(map);
  // Add a listener for the click event.
  adilabadBorder.addListener('click', showPanelAdila);
  // Add a listener for the click event.
  khammamBorder.addListener('click', showPanelKham);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function hideAllBoxOne() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('boxOne');
  for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

//Show table with info
function showPanelAdila() {
  hideAllBoxOne();
  document.getElementById('adilaDIV').style.display = "block";
}


//Show table with info
function showPanelKham() {
  hideAllBoxOne()
  document.getElementById('khamDIV').style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="adilaDIV" class="boxOne" style="display:none">
  <table id="adilaTable" class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>ADILABAD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Population</td>
      <td>2,930,604</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Percent Adults</td>
      <td>81%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Life Expectancy</td>
      <td>65</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="khamDIV" class="boxOne" style="display:none">
  <table id="khamTable" class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>KHAMMAM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Population</td>
      <td>3,654,765</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Percent Adults</td>
      <td>81%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Life Expectancy</td>
      <td>65</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection (`getElementById` returns a single Node). So you have to iterate each item and hide it.

JQuery do this by return a jQuery collection from the method `$`.

```js
function hideAll() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('cls'), function(node) {
    node.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="cls">class 1</div>
<div class="cls">class 2</div>
<div class="cls">class 3</div>
<div class="cls">class 4</div>
<button onclick="hideAll()">Hide All</button>
```

Comment: I tested all three answers and they all work for me, thanks so much.

Comment: Our pleasure ☺ Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I use something similar for tabs. So here the js code adapted to your divs.
Pass the divID you want to display to the function (like: "adilaDIV"), all other will be hidden.

```
function setDivs(divId) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("boxeOne");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       if (x[i] == divId) {
         x[i].style.display = "block";
       } else {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
       }
    }
}
```